# Controller Method in MVC not called

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I got quite a simple JS-Method:

```
<script language="javascript">   
    function AmountChanged(callingTextbox) {                 
        var enteredQuantity = callingTextbox.value;
        $.getJSON("/Catalog/GetEnteredQuantity",
        {
            id: enteredQuantity
        },
        function (data) {
            alert(data.MoneyText);                
        });
    }
</script>
```

This "should" call a function in my Controller:

```
public partial class CatalogController : BaseController {
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetEnteredQuantity(object id)
    {
        var result = new { MoneyText = "kost nix" };
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Through Chrome I can see that the JavaScript function is called. The debugger steps through until the line  `$.getJSON("/Catalog/GetEnteredQuantity",` and then jumps to the last closing bracket of that JS-Function. But the GetEnteredQuantity()-Method is never called.

The console shows a `"http://localhost:2451/Catalog/GetEnteredQuantity?id=48 404 Not Found"`

What is wrong here?

Comment: that's because your AJAX call is generating a `GET Request` and your controller is configured to accept `POST requests`, try removing `[HttpPost]` from your controller

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. If you write this as an answer I will flag it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the HttpPost attribute from the action**

```
public partial class CatalogController : BaseController {
    [HttpPost] //Remove it
    public JsonResult GetEnteredQuantity(object id)
    {
        var result = new { MoneyText = "kost nix" };
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Drew already answered this (old) question in the comments. Thanks nonetheless :)